# Margin space needs to be 0px

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am learning web-designing. Trying to replicate a web for practice. Everything seem to be OK.However the space between the nav bar and the first div takes 20px margin space. I want the margin space to be 0px. The css file hold margin as 0px but there is always 20px when I inspect the page. how do i solve this? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: please always provide some example code of what you have achieved. Happy coding!

Comment: Can you please share your code snippet? or any live example if you have.

Comment: this might be the browsers default stylings issue

Comment: This might be order of appearance of your stylesheet... Make your css file before the existing css file

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the css class that has the 20px margin by using

```
.className {
    margin: 0px !importart;
}
```

Comment: I personally always prefer not to use !important. Should implement HTML & CSS in a way that it doesn't require much overriding.

Comment: I understand your point because it's a bad practice but doesn't mean it's not okay to use !important. 

Can you please provide a code snippet or screen shot for the sample code?

Comment: We certainly shouldn't be recommending to use `!important` unless you know for sure that it is necessary - which in this case we don't. That is why you should wait until the question is edited to include enough information to be able to give an accurate answer - or just not answer it at all: see [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): "*Not all questions can or should be answered here. Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem*".

Answer (score 0):

As you suggested i tried the above soln.It didnt work.
I am sending an image and the code.. hope it helps.

```css
  .navbar {
      padding-top: 15px;
      padding-bottom: 15px;
      border: 0;
      border-radius: 0;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      font-size: 12px;
      letter-spacing: 5px;
  }
  .navbar-nav  li a:hover {
      color: #1abc9c !important;
  }
```

[the image is for the inspect of the nar bar...where the margin is not accepting 0px.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AC6mS.png)